# lines of a class in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class in Java which is written bellow.I want to know does that has normal size or it is big and huge and should be broken into some pieces:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class AddressTree
{

    private AddressNode structureRoot, userRoot;
    private String xmlAddress;

    public AddressTree(String XMLaddress)
    {
        this.xmlAddress = XMLaddress;
        createEmptyTree();
        startParsing();
    }

    private void startParsing()
    {
        AddressXMLParser handler = new AddressXMLParser(this);
        try
        {
            SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            File xml = new File(xmlAddress);
            parser.parse(xml, handler);
            ArrayList<AddressNode> rawNodes = createRawNodes(handler.getAddressStructure());
            createTreeFromRawNodes(rawNodes, handler.getStartItem());
            for (int i = 0; i < handler.getFinalItems().size(); i++)
            {
                getAddressNode(handler.getFinalItems().get(i), structureRoot).setIsFinal(true);
            }
        }
        catch (StartAddressNodeNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(AddressTree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (SAXException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void createEmptyTree()
    {
        structureRoot = new AddressNode("root", null);
        userRoot = new AddressNode("root", null);
    }

    public void setValue(String nodeName, String value) throws AddressNodeNotFoundException
    {
        AddressNode node = getAddressNode(nodeName, userRoot);
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.setNodeValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AddressNodeNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCompleteAddress()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isAddressCompleted()
    {
        AddressNode iterator = userRoot;
        while (iterator.getAllChilds().size() != 0)
        {
            iterator = iterator.getAllChilds().get(0);
        }
        if (getAddressNode(iterator.getNodeName(), structureRoot).isFinal())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<String> getSubAddressItems(String addressItem)
    {
        ArrayList<String> subAddressItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<AddressNode> childNodes = getAddressNode(addressItem, structureRoot).getAllChilds();
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.size(); i++)
        {
            subAddressItems.add(childNodes.get(i).getNodeName());
        }
        return subAddressItems;
    }

    private AddressNode getAddressNode(String nodeName, AddressNode root)
    {
        ArrayList<AddressNode> graphNodes = new ArrayList<AddressNode>();
        ArrayList<AddressNode> passedNodes = new ArrayList<AddressNode>();
        graphNodes.add(root);
        while (graphNodes.size() != 0)
        {
            AddressNode cureNode = graphNodes.remove(0);
            passedNodes.add(cureNode);
            if (cureNode.getNodeName().equals(nodeName))
            {
                return cureNode;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cureNode.getAllChilds().size(); i++)
                {
                    if (!passedNodes.contains(cureNode.getAllChilds().get(i)))
                    {
                        graphNodes.add(cureNode.getAllChilds().get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private ArrayList<AddressNode> createRawNodes(TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> addressStructure)
    {
        int itemsSize = addressStructure.size();
        ArrayList<AddressNode> tmpNodes = new ArrayList<AddressNode>();
        ArrayList<AddressNode> finalNodes = new ArrayList<AddressNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsSize; i++)
        {
            String curKey = addressStructure.firstKey();
            ArrayList<String> curSubItems = addressStructure.remove(curKey);
            AddressNode curNode = new AddressNode(curKey);
            finalNodes.add(new AddressNode(curKey));
            for (int j = 0; j < curSubItems.size(); j++)
            {
                curNode.addChlid(curSubItems.get(j));
            }
            tmpNodes.add(curNode);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < finalNodes.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tmpNodes.get(i).getAllChilds().size(); j++)
            {
                AddressNode childNode = null;
                boolean existNodeBefore = false;
                for (int k = 0; k < finalNodes.size(); k++)
                {
                    if (finalNodes.get(k).getNodeName().equals(tmpNodes.get(i).getAllChilds().get(j).getNodeName()))
                    {
                        childNode = finalNodes.get(k);
                        existNodeBefore = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!existNodeBefore)
                {
                    finalNodes.get(i).addChlid(tmpNodes.get(i).getAllChilds().get(j).getNodeName());
                }
                else
                {
                    finalNodes.get(i).addChildNode(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
        return finalNodes;
    }

    private void createTreeFromRawNodes(ArrayList<AddressNode> rawNodes, String rootName) throws StartAddressNodeNotFoundException
    {
        if (rootName == null)
        {
            throw new StartAddressNodeNotFoundException();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rawNodes.size(); i++)
        {
            if (rawNodes.get(i).getNodeName().equals(rootName))
            {
                structureRoot.addChildNode(rawNodes.get(i));
                rawNodes.get(i).setParent(structureRoot);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addAddressItem(String itemName) throws AddressStructureAbusingException
    {
        AddressNode iterator = userRoot;
        while (iterator.getAllChilds().size() > 0)
        {
            iterator = iterator.getAllChilds().get(0);
        }
        AddressNode fatherNode = getAddressNode(iterator.getNodeName(), structureRoot);
        for (int i = 0; i < fatherNode.getAllChilds().size(); i++)
        {
            if (fatherNode.getAllChilds().get(i).getNodeName().equals(itemName))
            {
                iterator.addChlid(itemName);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new AddressStructureAbusingException();
    }

    public void removeLastAddressItem() throws AddressNodeNotFoundException
    {
        if (userRoot.getAllChilds().size() > 0)
        {
            AddressNode iterator = userRoot;
            while (iterator.getAllChilds().get(0).getAllChilds().size() > 0)
            {
                iterator = iterator.getAllChilds().get(0);
            }
            iterator.clearChilds();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AddressNodeNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

if it has to be broken how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has 230 lines - that's by no means excessive. However, size alone is only a very vague indicator of whether a class should be broken up.

A more general indicator is [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) - basically, most of a class's methods should be using most of its fields. But that also isn't a problem in your class - it looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

I've certainly seen bigger classes than that.

If you're finding it hard to read, I <s>suggest</s> *strongly recommend* putting some comments in there.

As long as your class revolves around a specific purpose, it should be as big as it needs to be to perform that purpose.

Comment: I know a lot of people do not attempt to use Object Oriented Rules but that does not mean I should not too. so I want to know the reality

Comment: There are no guidelines to say how big your class should be. It should be as big as it needs to be to perform the job you need it to perform.

Comment: I refactored classes of 35 klocs.. it was a miserable job :( 

this is a very small one :) :)

Answer (score 2):

it has several responsibilites as I can see:

- XML parsing (**the representation**)
- XML manipulation (`AddressNode`)
- hold parsing's output (**the model**)

at least I separate these two responsabilities in at least two separated classes.

**NB**

not concerned by the question there are also several empty catch blocks, [see here why they are a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Good catch on the catches (pun intended).

Comment: 'More classes' isn't always the answer. Unless the components that you are going to break out are going to also be (re)usable in some other context, there really is not much utility in breaking them out as separate classes. In fact, if the only purpose of the logic of the parsing (and what-not) is to support the central data structure, then you'd just have these extra classes with relatively high coupling between them. Not saying more classes is not the answer here, just that there's no hard and fast rule and it's a good idea to carefully consider such changes.

Comment: XML parsing has been done in another class which is AddressXMLParser and the reason that I put the part of the parsing in this class is to hide the nodes and structure of tree from parser so I don't realy know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to adapt

```
if (foo) {
   bar();
} else {
   fum();
}
```

instead.   This allows the code to be shorter in length, allowing you to see more at once on the screen.

Also.  Never have empty catch blocks.  Consider "throw new RuntimeException("unexpected", e)" in them.