# jQuery.animate({left: 0}) error in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate

In IE8, the line `$liElement.animate({left:0},500);` breaks the page with an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.   `$liElement` is the jQuery object I get from `$('#mydiv li').eq(0);`

`$liElement.animate({},500);` does not cause an error.

I am using jQuery 1.5.1.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it work for other non-zero values?

Comment: @Diodeus, no - it doesn't work for any values.  Neither does `right`

Comment: is your `<li>` element absolutely positioned?

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi, No, but it is nested inside an absolutely positioned `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the source of this, you'll have to run this code under a debugger and find out (1) which object it's complaining about (2) which property or method it's complaining about.  Then, you can work backward to see whose assumption is incorrect.  Perhaps you could post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that has a minimal test case?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the call in a try catch:

```
try {
    // animate  
} catch (e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: [Rule #43](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea): Empty `catch` blocks are ***evil***.

Comment: unless @Chris intended to place something in the catch block, like a console.log(e) or debugger statement...

Comment: @Dan D, you might be right, and I'll definitely cancel the downvote if @Chris does so. But `wrap the call in a try catch` does not give me much hope.

Comment: @Frederic, Am i supposed to know what the person who posted the question wants to do on failure? That wasn't even the question.

Comment: @Chris, well, `animate()` should not fail like this on IE8. Swallowing the exception silently with an empty `catch` block, as you're suggesting, will not help solving that problem.

Comment: @Frederic, i said use a try catch. i'm not writing the code.  Nor did the question say how an error should be handled. But this does address the question. If you know better, why don't you enlighten us.

Comment: @Chris @Frederic the answer changed; when originally written, the //handle error comment was absent.  That caused Frederic to assume that the point of the answer was to swallow the error silently and start this comment war.  It's since changed; I still think it's the wrong solution, because it doesn't address the fundamental source of the error, but Mr. Hamidi's reason for downvoting no longer applies.

Comment: @Dan D, downvote is now lifted (I had to edit @Chris's answer to be allowed to do that). Apologies to both of you for the comment war, it wasn't my intent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the element either absolutely or relatively positioned. Otherwise a value for left will be ignored.

Comment: I tried prefixing the call with both `$liElement.css('position','relative')` and `liElement.css('position','absolute')`.  Neither fixed the error