# empty catch blocks in the same line

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, code-formatting

I prefer to have all opening curly braces on a new line:

```
if (foo)
{
    bar();
}
```

Can I configure the Eclipse code formatter to put empty catch blocks in the same line?

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch (ImpossibleCheckedException ignore) {}
```

I have already found the option to put the curly braces of an empty block on a single line (`New Lines`, `[ ] in empty block`), but not on the same line as the catch. And yes, I really want that empty catch block.

Comment: You really should think about that. Empty catch blocks can be overlooked when the code in the try block is changed. Also there is no indication as to _why_ you deem the exception ignorable. The best is to provide a small comment that explains that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done, at least the Eclipse formatter does not support this.

p.s. Due to the discussion on the other answers (which are now deleted), I feel obliged to stay on topic but add this comment: Empty catch blocks are bad m'kay [Why are empty catch blocks a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234343/569659)

Comment: @FredOverflow - you should remove your down-vote now.  This is the only correct, on-topic answer you will get.