# Reading from the file with Scanner.useDelimiter() and hasNextLine() - NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, file-handling, nosuchelementexception

When I try to load the data from the **textfile**, with data like this

```
java;sdf;2.0;3.0;
cpp;sdks;24.6;89.0;
```

I'm getting the `NoSuchElementException` with this code.

```
public void loadFile() {
  Scanner scan = null;  
  int n = 0;
  try {
     scan = new Scanner(new File(this.filename)).useDelimiter(";");
     this.items.clear();
     
     while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = scan.next();
        String barcode = scan.next();
        double unitPrice = scan.nextDouble();
        double shipCost = scan.nextDouble();

        Product newProduct = new Product(name, barcode, unitPrice, shipCost);
        this.items.add(newProduct);
        n++;
     }
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
     System.err.println("Caught InputMismatchException: " + e.getMessage());
     System.out.println(n + " products loaded!");
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
     System.err.println("Attempt to read past end of file");
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     System.err.println("Attempt to read a closed file");
  } finally {
     if (scan != null)
        scan.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Such Element Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032099/no-such-element-exception)

Answer (score 0):

hasNextLine() method waits unitl there is no nextLine
but hasNext() waits until there is next token

For solution perspective use :

```
 while (scan.hasNext()) {
            String name = scan.next();
            String barcode = scan.next();
            double unitPrice = scan.nextDouble();
            double shipCost = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println(name);

            n++;
         }
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: even with the hasNext() method, i'm getting the NoSuchElementException

Comment: running in my local machine fine

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches how you can solve this.

**1.** Advance to the next line when all token on the current line have been read.

For that, add the line `scan.nextLine()` at the end of the *loop*. Method `nextLine()` will return the whole current line (that value will be omitted) and will set the scanners position at the beginning of the next line.

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    // reading tokens and creating new Product

    scan.nextLine();
}
```

**2.** *Change the condition* in the `while` loop to `scan.hasNext()`.  So that it'll check whether more token exists.

But another problem will arise: stating from the second *item* all *item names* will contain a new line character (`\n`) at the beginning.

To handle it, you can either apply `strip()` on a *name*, change the delimiter to `"[;\\r\\n]+" (with that every new line character` \n`and carriage return`\r` character as well as semicolon will be omitted.

```
can = new Scanner(new File(this.filename)).useDelimiter("[;\\r\\n]+");
this.items.clear();
            
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    // code inside the loop remains the same
}
```

*The drawback of this approach*: condition `scan.hasNext()` that check existence of a single token doesn't clearly show the intention to read the line comprised of four tokens.

**3.** The last option is to read the file line by line with `scan.nextLine()` and then apply `split(";")` on it, which will give an array of strings.

This solution might look a bit more tedious because it'll require to handle the splitting to parse `double` values manually.

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(";");
    String name = line[0];
    String barcode = line[1];
    double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
    double shipCost = Double.parseDouble(line[3]);

    Product newProduct = new Product(name, barcode, unitPrice, shipCost);
    this.items.add(newProduct);
}
```

All solutions above are tested with the provided *file-example* and a dummy `Product` class.

**Output** (`items` list contents)

```
[Product{name='java', barcode='sdf', unitPrice=2.0, shipCost=3.0}, Product{name='cpp', barcode='sdks', unitPrice=24.6, shipCost=89.0}]
```

Comment: The third option worked, thanks a lot!