# Compare 2 different columns in the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, telerik

In my `datagridview`, four columns 1 & 2 are read only col 3 & 4 got number values. I want to compare that 4th column must be greater that 3rd column. 
For example:

[image]

If the 4th column value is less than the 3rd column then I want to propose message doesn't navigate to another control.

My simple approach seems not working. How can I compare 2 specific columns for this kind of condition?

```
private void datagridview_CellValidating(object sender, CellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int bbor = datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int ebor = datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if (ebor <= bbor)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please verify the value");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the column and row indexes? Grab the value from each cell at the appropriate location and compare the values, not the indexes.

Comment: In some cases, in the datagridview it may have 8 rows, I can't compare each and every row. BY row & col index may be better.. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thank u;

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @linguini Lemme know if you need help my answer and we can hit up chat again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we meet again. Use the cell_click event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 0)
    {
        if (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()) <= Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please verify the value");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** This seems to work fine, lemme know.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 0)
    {
        if (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()) <= Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please verify the value");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: Updated for Telerik controls**

```
private void radGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0)
        {
            if (e.Value != null && radGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value != null)
            {
                if (Double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) <= Double.Parse(radGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                    e.Cancel = true;                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Good to see you again, thank you. If i use e.cancel it's seems it's not working.

Comment: @linguini Are you wanting to have the message pop up when they change the value? Or are you wanting it to popup when clicking in the cell?

Comment: Actually, If the 4th col value is less than 3rd Col value(right from the first row) then the user shouldn't navigate to another cell. Thats why i'm trying to cell validating. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you

Comment: @linguini I added an edit to my post. I tested it and basically it makes the user close the messagebox while maintaining focus on the current cell that needs to be addressed. What are you getting, an error perhaps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19181/discussion-between-linguini-and-kreepn)

Comment: I have sent an email to you. Thank you.

Comment: @linguini I'll check it out when I have a few minutes, working on a dev item atm :). I'll respond here when I do.

Comment: @linguini I don't see an email, even in my junk. got_die@hotmail.com -> Try it again.

Comment: àKreepN just sent once agin.

Answer (score 1):

I'd see something more or less like that:

If you want to check all rows:

```
DataRow dr;
for(int i = datagridview.Rows.Count-1; i > 0; i--) {
    dr = datagridview.Rows[i];
    if(dr[e.ColumnIndex] > dr[e.ColumnIndex+1]){
            //your message code     
            e.Cancel = true;
        break; (or return;)
    }
}
```

If you want to check only the current row where the cell is being edited:

```
DataRow dr = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex];
e.Cancel = dr[e.ColumnIndex] > dr[e.ColumnIndex+1];
if(e.Cancel)
    //your message code
```

Maybe you will need to convert objects to int for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

See the Rows Property for DataGridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

> this.dataGridView1[col, row].Value

references a specific cell for each row

```
foreach (Row r in this.dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (r.Cells[3].Value <= r.Cells[2].Value ) {
    System.Console.WriteLine ("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you exactly. I tried your code, it's not working.

Comment: int cell = (int) r.Cells[2].Value;
                    int cells = (int) r.Cells[3].Value;
                    if (cells <= cell)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("check");
                    }

Answer (score 1):

For your validation check you'll want to use the [`FormattedValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.formattedvalue.aspx) to see what value your user wants to insert in the cell they've edited.  You can't use the current cell value because it doesn't update to the new value until after the `CellValidating` completes without `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs.Cancel` being set to true.

Something like this:

```
private void datagridview_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) {
    // This is the new proposed value the user entered; could be for column 3 or 4.
    int newValue = int.Parse(e.FormattedValue.ToString());

    // See which column fired the CellValidating event and use the new proposed value for it
    // in place of the cell's actual value for purposes of our validation.
    int col3Value = (e.ColumnIndex == 2) ? newValue : (int)dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value;
    int col4Value = (e.ColumnIndex == 3) ? newValue : (int)dataGridView1[3, e.RowIndex].Value;

    if (col3Value <= col4Value) {
        MessageBox.Show("Please verify the value");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The code I show here is to demonstrate a solution to your problem.  In your actual production code 
you'll want to verify that casting from object to int is successful (through [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)) or catch the exception that's raised when this operation fails.  When this happens you can `Cancel = true` the cell validation and present to the user a message that he must enter a number.

And another quick note: [don't use empty catch blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea) (though I realize this probably isn't in your production code).

Comment: I'm getting a error message, can't apply indexing to an expression type.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?  Also, are you using a DataGridView?  If you are then your second parameter should be of type `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs`.