# Compare Old Cell and New cell values in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView. I have to compare the old and the new cell values and perform further action.

I tried comparing with `Cell Leave`, `CellValidating` events by using the following code,

```
private void TestGrid_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    var oldCellValue = TestGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    var newValue = e.FormattedValue;
}
```

It returns my Old value and new value both as eg: 1000 when I try clicking on the different cell.

Please, let me know if there is any other event through which I can achieve the desired behaviour.
Also If I have to compare the old and new cells row or column indexes then how to proceed?

```
private void TestGrid_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int oldCell = e.ColumnIndex;        
}
```

Both them returns same index.

Comment: How do you bind the datagrid DataSource? That source of data could have all the info you need

Comment: maybe this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259013/compare-2-different-columns-in-the-datagridview

Comment: Steve I bind data as,TestGrid.DataSource = dt;

Comment: You want to compare value of the same cell before and after user edit it or compare value of the new current cell and the previously current cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `EditedFormattedValue` property of the `DataGridView`. Tested this one and I see the different values:

```
private void TestGrid_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    var oldValue = TestGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    var newValue = TestGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;
    /* Perform some logic here*/
}
```

Comment: it is not allowing me to use editformated property,its saying,
"System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'EditedFormattedValue' and no extension method 'EditedFormattedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs' could be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: In some instances i need to compare just column indexes then how will it work like for eg:
private void TestGrid_CellLeave(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int currentCell = TestGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int oldCell = e.ColumnIndex;
         

        }

Comment: Opps, check edit... my bad.. Was too lazy to change the name of the grid, because in my test project its datagridview1 so I just copied yours and replaced the property, but forgot that you have to use the index...

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the cell values into strings and do something similar like this (code example comes from MSDN). Hope this helps.

```
// Iterate through the SelectedCells collection and sum up the values. 
for (counter = 0;
    counter < (DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count); counter++)
{
    if (DataGridView1.SelectedCells[counter].FormattedValueType ==
        Type.GetType("System.String"))
    {
        string value = null;

        // If the cell contains a value that has not been commited, 
        // use the modified value. 
        if (DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty == true)
        {

            value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells[counter]
                .EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            value = DataGridView1.SelectedCells[counter]
                .FormattedValue.ToString();
        }
        if (value != null)
        {
            // Ignore cells in the Description column. 
            if (DataGridView1.SelectedCells[counter].ColumnIndex !=
                DataGridView1.Columns["Description"].Index)
            {
                if (value.Length != 0)
                {
                    SelectedCellTotal += int.Parse(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not helping to compare indexes.