# How do I properly use a SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have 2 methods as below :

```
internal static SqlDataReader SelectData(string sql)
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Constant.ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
        var dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        return dataReader;
    }
}
```

============

And using this method as :

```
var dataReader = SelectData(---some sql ---);

private void AddData(dataReader)
{
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.FirstNamei = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
    }

    dataReader.Close();
}
```

I know we can merge this two method, but I am looking at better way write this, OR this can cause some problem??

Comment: You mention that you are using the first method in the second but that is not true. Both methods seem to be unrelated  to each other, so your question is still unclear. Btw, [**never** use empty `catch`-blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1234364/284240).

Comment: @TimSchmelter .. Thats correct..I edited..

Comment: Why not use Enterprise Libraries for data access?

Comment: @T.S. - I'm surprised [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) is still maintained.  It used to be the shiznit, but I haven't heard of it in a long time.

Comment: Not just maintained. It had new version recently. It works faster than EF and has caching capabilities. I think, it worth implementing than create connections on every page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you are in fact leaving yourself open a bit. You really want to write it like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
{
    // use parameters in your SQL statement too, so you can do this
    // and protect yourself from SQL injection, so for example
    // SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = @parm1
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm1", val1);

    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {

    }
}
```

because you need to make **sure** these objects get disposed. Further, by going this direction you don't need `dataReader.Close()`. It will get called when it gets automatically disposed by the `using` statement.

Now, wrap that collection of statements inside a `try...catch` and you're in business.

Comment: I was just trying to refactor it..so that I can use a method like `SelectData` everywhere..What you gave is a great working piece of code..

Comment: For the sake of clarity the first set of braces is unnecessary.

using(SqlConnection cnn = n.....)
using(SqlCommand cmd = n.....)
{
// Code
}

Just saves on so much nesting. Using statements can go back to back

Comment: @Hawxby, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I've submitted an edit. You can use using statements without braces between each one using() using() using () {}

Comment: @Hawxby, nice little syntactic sugar. Thanks for the addition

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things

1) Since you're closing your connection on `SelectData`, `dataReader` should blow up on `AddData` as it requires an open connection

2) `AddData` shouldn't close dataReader as he didn't open it.

3) Maybe you're hiding some code but I don't see that you use `Employee` instance created on `AddData`

Comment: That means, the datareader is blank when I am accessing in AddData method??

Comment: @Ratan: not blank, It should throw an error as connection is not longer active.

Comment: IS there some place, where I can see some ideal way to write such type of methods..Because for each type of `Employee e = new Employee();` I need to write the whole thing again and again..

Answer (score 0):

Technically, first method would be correct if you would do

```
    sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Then, your client would close the reader and your connection will be closed as well.

Second example would also be correct if you didn't close the reader inside of it. There is no criminal in passing the reader to a method just to iterate it. but it has to be controlled from where it was created. How you open and dispose of it - this is different question.