# Pinging a server faster in Java?

Tags: java, performance, ip, ping

I'm trying to see what IP's on a list are actually online. I'm currently using

```
    public boolean IsOnline(String ip) { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket(ip, 80)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

To check if the server is online. But it takes about 30 seconds for each IP to get checked. Is there a way to get faster results like another kind of method?

Comment: Furthermore, a server can be online but not be listening on port 80

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but would `INetAddress.isReachable` suffice for your needs? You can't do ICMP messages in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [INetAddress.isReachable](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

> ".. A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the
>   privilege can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP
>   connection on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host..".

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can imagine, why this takes 30 seconds is, that nobody listens to port 80 and your socket connection timeout is 30 seconds. Please check for this by adding `ex.printStackTrace()` within the catch clause.

Please take a read here: [Why are empty catch blocks a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea)

How you should "ping" a server, depends on what ports it is listening to. Normally `INetAdresse.isReachable()` works good. If your administrator blocks ICMP requests you may use the ssh port 22, to probe for the servers existence.

Comment: Java doesn't normally use ICMP requests for `isReachable()` anyway, it uses TCP port 7.