# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! with a sort algo that should be 100% stable

Tags: java, exception, comparator, illegalargumentexception

No idea how this could ever be unstable. This works fine on most cases, but throws IllegalArgumentException with some queries.

That is all, can't think of more relevant details.

```
private static void sortSearchResults(List<Map> l){
        Comparator<Map> comp = new Comparator<Map>(){
            public int compare(Map a,Map b){
                int aa=0,ba=0,as=0,bs=0;
                try{
                    aa = Integer.parseInt(""+a.get("activity"));

                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
                try{
                    ba = Integer.parseInt(""+b.get("activity"));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
                try{
                    as = Integer.parseInt(""+a.get("searchscore"));

                }catch(Exception ex){
                }
                try{
                    bs = Integer.parseInt(""+b.get("searchscore"));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }


                if(as>bs)
                    return -1;
                else if(bs<as)
                    return 1;
                else{
                    if(aa>ba)
                        return -1;
                    else if(aa<ba)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }

            }
            public boolean equals(Object o){
                return o==this;
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(l,comp);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: Why not? I don't really want to do anything with the exception, and it gets thrown when searchscore or activity is null.

Comment: Search on the web. Also look here maybe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(as>bs)
    return -1;
else if(bs<as)
    return 1;
```

`as>bs` and `bs<as` mean exactly the same thing. You probably meant:

```
if(as<bs)
    return -1;
else if(as>bs)
    return 1;
```