# Request.QueryString in Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, request.querystring

I have this **ImageButton** and **Label** in my **GridView**

*Grid Definition is as follows*

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send kwm">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="Sendkwm" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/check.gif"
                OnClick="Sendkwm" />
        </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <center>
            <asp:Label ID="kwm" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("kwm").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </center>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My problem is I need to use the querystring value of kwm to update which column of data I'm going to display.

I searched on the web but it seems that it is necessary to use the GridView the SqlDataSource, is there any alternative to do this alternative method ?

My **code-behind** below.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
protected void Sendkwm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OdbcConnection conn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sql = " UPDATE doTable " +
               " SET myDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP () " +
               " WHERE " +
               "    kwm =  //here the querystring value of kwm// ; ";

        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql,conn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the datasource that you are using to bind the grid ?

Comment: Why do you use a GridView which is used for multiple rows but with a single `QueryString`-parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use the codebehind, especially the `GridView`'s [`RowDataBound`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx). That makes your code also more robust since you get compile time safety and it's also more readable/maintainable:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton sendKwm =  (ImageButton) e.Row.FindControl("Sendkwm ");
        Label lblKwm = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("kwm");
        lblKwm.Text = Request.QueryString["kwm"]; 
    }
}
```

Now you get the value in the `ImageButton`'s click-event handler in the following way:

```
protected void Sendkwm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton sendKwm = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) sendKwm.NamingContainer;
    Label lblKwm = (Label)row.FindControl("kwm");

    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = @"UPDATE doTable 
                       SET myDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                       WHERE kwm = @kwm;";

        using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kwm", lblKwm.Text);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            } finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that i've used sql-parameters to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @Hamamelis: also note that `catch (Exception ex){ throw ex; }` is evil. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex