# How to delete some specific sheets from an existing excel file using vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net

I was trying the below vb.net code to delete some specific sheets from an excel file but it doesn't give me the result what I expected. Actually I need to add that vb.net code into 'Invoke vba' activity in UiPath. Here I have attached all the snapshots of my work. I'm very new to the vb.net and need a clarification for the below code.

```
Try

app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
workbook= app.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
TryCast(workbook.Sheets(sheetName),Worksheet).Delete()
workbook.Save
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")(0).Kill

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

[image: Declared variables, Their types and receptive values]

Comment: You said _doesn't give me the result what I expected_. What result are you getting?

Comment: the empty catch statement could be a first sign of an issue...empty catch statements are a personal pet peeve of mine...that has the information you need to tell you what's wrong

Comment: Agreed. Empty `Catch` blocks should absolutely never be used. Have a look at the top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Do you really need to use VB.NET code? Alternatively, you could just send the appropriate hotkeys to delete the worksheet: https://forum.uipath.com/t/delete-one-sheet-in-excel/22323/3

Comment: Please only use tags that are relevant to your question.

Comment: @JayV Actually I wanted to delete some specific sheets from the excel file. But unfortunately it didn't delete sheets as I expected, apart from that it recreated the same sheet again. Now the problem is solved and I have added the corrected code by my self. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a output of Excel application scope workbook as ExcelWorkbook

Using ExcelWorkbook.GetSheets you get the sheets, iterate it with for each loop as
foreach item in ExcelWorkbook.GetSheets

now you have a every single worksheet name you can perform delete operation or also skip it

Thanks!! Might it help you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your answers. Here I've solved it myself with including two small code lines as follows.

```
Try

    app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    workbook= app.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    TryCast(workbook.Sheets(sheetName),Worksheet).Delete()
    app.DisplayAlerts = True
    workbook.Save
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")(0).Kill

    Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```