# SonarQube -- can it be silenced with a hint?

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like to find a way to hint SonarQube so that it would not warn for some pieces of code.

Example1: "empty statement block can be removed" -- actually, it cannot be removed:

```
static void closeNX (java.io.FileInputStream is) {
    try {
        is.close ();
    } catch (Exception e) {} <Warning comes here>
}
```

(Edit: this method is called when `is.read` or `is.write` has already thrown an Exception, so any more Exception from `is.close` is not needed.)

Example2: `finalize` is deprecated, as the memory will be eventually released even if the user of your library forget to call `close`/`dispose` -- but native resources (opened files, sockets, IPC, whatever) won't be released, that's why for example `java.io.FileInputStream` does have `finalize` method:

```
protected void finalize() throws IOException {
    if ((fd != null) &&  (fd != FileDescriptor.in)) {
        close();
    }
}
```

(Edit: even having `finalize` doesn't warrant that native resources will be released if the user doesn't call `close`/`dispose`; but non-having `finalize` does warrant that native resources won't be released if the user doesn't call `close`/`dispose`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To silence the message you can either configure which rules are enabled in SonarQube by configuring your [quality profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/), or you can add [an exclusion](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) for particular file.

The third way is to add `// NOSONAR` comment on the line with the issue. However, this way you are muting all rules.

Now about the examples, you provided - empty catch block can't be removed, however, it's considered to be a code smell. Perhaps an exception should be at least logged? See here for more discussion [Why are empty catch blocks a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234343/why-are-empty-catch-blocks-a-bad-idea)

For finalize, it's not a good idea to use them to release resources because there is no guarantee when finalize will be invoked or if it will be invoked at all. It's better to release resources explicitly rather than rely on garbage collection to invoke finalize. You can check these bugs in JDK why even Java authors prefer not to use finalize in `java.io.FileInputStream` https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187325 , https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212050

Comment: Well, a `hint` or `pragma` in the source or a directive in the `sonar-projects.properties` would be useful, but never mind.

Comment: A source-level "hint" is a NOSONAR comment, you just shall RTFM.https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/faq/

Comment: @persicsb Thank you very much, it did work. Please write it as an Answer so that I can mark it as 'Accepted Answer'

Comment: I added it to my answer